# PCL SACSegmentation - setAxis and setModelType has no effect in Output

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to estimate the ground plane present in the pointcloud and remove it. I used the [plane model segmentation tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php#planar-segmentation) for that.

Instead of removing the ground plane it removes the vertical planes(wall) in the pointcloud.

I changed the axis perpendicular to which the plane is estimated but get the same result..

This is the code :-

```
  Eigen::Vector3f axis = Eigen::Vector3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);

  pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
  // Create the segmentation object
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZI> seg;
   seg.setAxis(axis);

  seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);

  seg.setModelType (pcl:: SACMODEL_PLANE);
  seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.5);

  seg.setInputCloud (cloud);
  seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
```

When I input a stream of pointclouds through ROS, I get Model coefficients as :-

```
Model coefficients: 0.980676 0.00643671 0.195532 0.127706
Model coefficients: 0.0974007 -0.00814183 0.995212 2.64382
Model coefficients: 0.0235566 -0.997725 -0.0631705 4.7102
Model coefficients: 0.0404465 -0.999113 -0.0117141 4.65797
```

ie sometimes it removes ground plane and at some other instant it removes walls... the coordinate system in the pointcloud is

```
x axis -> forward
y axis -> right
z axis -> up
```

Now since ground plane is along x-z plane perpendicular to y axis I set the Axis as (0.0,1.0,0.0) so that according to [PCL api](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_s_a_c_segmentation.html#a23abc3e522ccb2b2846a6c9b0cf7b7d3)
ground_plane perpendicular to y axis be removed... but as i said only at some instants it is removed and at other instants vetical planes (wall) gets removed...

I tried all possibilities of (1,0,0) ,(0,1,0),(0,0,1) but it has NO EFFECT in the output result...The same result I mentioned above is obtained...

Also changed ModelType to SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE ,  SACMODEL_PARALLEL_PLANE ,still no desired result

Please pour in your suggestions where I am going wrong..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61811/pcl-sacsegmentation---setaxis-and-setmodeltype-has-no-effect-in-output/) by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to also set the `eps_angle` parameter.

If you check the source code for [sac_model_parallel_plane.hpp](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/sac__model__parallel__plane_8hpp_source.html), you'll see that the axis is only used in the `isModelValid()` function.  And, even then, only when `eps_angle_ > 0`.  Looking in [sac_model_parallel_plane.h](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/sac__model__parallel__plane_8h_source.html), we see that `eps_angle_` is initialized to 0.  So, unless you explicitly set this parameter, the model will effectively ignore the parallel-to-axis constraint.

Try adding this:

```
seg.setEpsAngle(  30.0f * (M_PI/180.0f) );
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-30**:
Thank you Jeremy.. So is the angle parameter signify angle tolerance of plane with the axis or its normal with the axis??? (as it is in this : http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_s_a_c_segmentation.html )

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-04-30**:
Read the PCL documentation for setEpsAngle() at the link you provided.  It is: "maximum allowed difference between the model NORMAL and the given axis in radians".  So, the "axis" parameter is the expected plane normal vector, and "epsAngle" is the allowable variation for a plane to count as "valid"

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-05-01**:
Thank u Jeremy.... tat worked!!! now only the ground plane gets removed...

but Still at some instants nothing  gets removed... do you know wat could be the reason behind it... I tried values for epsAngle from 20 to 45 ....any rectification to be made ??

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-05-01**:
Also what is the difference between SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE and SACMODEL_PARALLEL_PLANE... I get the same result for both!!!

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-05-01**:
Your questions are fairly specific to PCL, and are not really ROS-related.  You should try addressing these questions to the PCL user's list: pcl-users@pointclouds.org.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-04-22**:
hi i have the same problem. In my pointcloud, the wall is a dominant plane, everytime i tried to extract the ground (set axis method) it still gives me the wall. How did you solve your problem

**Comment by [daviddoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/25239/daviddoria/) on 2015-12-02**:
I also have the same problem. It should return a plane that is within the 'epsAngle' of the specified 'axis' even if one doesn't fit well, right? It seems like what is happening is that there are 0 inliers in the model that is found (which should be an error condition?).